# Leaftet google integration - attribution links not working

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaftlet (version 0.7.7) with Google plugin (https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins - version 1.9.3) and I noticed that google attribution links (Terms of use, Report a map error) are not clickable. Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Are you aware of GoogleMutant for Leaflet 1.0?

Comment: Did you know you can use google tiles without plugin with leaflet with this URL : ```http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}``` ?

Comment: @JulienV although using this URL may technically work, it is _legally against_ the Google Maps Terms of Use.

Comment: @ghybs I didn't know. Thanks

Comment: We just find out about GoogleMutant, thank you @IvanSanchez. We consider to use it in long term but for now we need to find a fix attribution links.